# How do I synchronize these two timers in my mvc project?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, timer

I have this session expire time in my web.config, that only redirects upon expire if the user attempts a HttpPost, and I'm guessing it resets the timer after each HttpPost:

```
<system.web>
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="60" />
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login/Login"></forms>
</authentication>
```

And I have this javascript code in my _Layout.cshtml that will redirecet to login if the user is idle, and I'm taking a wild guess here that it resets after an ajaxcall:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var _redirectTimeout = 60 * 60 * 1000;
        var _redirectUrl = '@Url.Action("Logout", "Login")';

        var _redirectHandle = null;

        function resetRedirect() {
            if (_redirectHandle) clearTimeout(_redirectHandle);
            _redirectHandle = setTimeout(function () {
                window.location.href = _redirectUrl;
            }, _redirectTimeout);
        }
//EDIT1
$(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, request, settings) {
if(request.status === 403) {
   // reset timer
//resetRedirect();
 window.location.href = _redirectUrl; //Im a dumbass, It should be this but it still doesnt work...
}
});

        /*$.ajaxSetup({
            complete: function () {
                resetRedirect();

            }
        });*/ // reset idle redirect when an AJAX request completes
        resetRedirect(); // start idle redirect timer initially.
    });
</script>
```

**This makes my two timers (both with 60 mins) asynchronous, any idea how I can fix this?** I think I should make the javascript synchronous with HttpPost but I dont know how...

**EDIT1** I edited my java script code above with JesseJames suggestion, and tried testing it with the code below, but the resetRedirect(); just doesnt trigger:

```
$('.save-table').on('click', function () {
                var tr = $(this).parents('tr:first');
                var PredefName = tr.find("#PredefName").val();
                var PredefDescription = tr.find("#PredefDescription").val();
                var PredefID = tr.find("#PredefID").html();
                tr.find("#lblPredefName").text(PredefName);
                tr.find("#lblPredefDescription").text(PredefDescription);
                tr.find('.edit-mode, .display-mode').toggle();

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/PredefinedViews/Update/',
                    data: JSON.stringify({ pID: PredefID, pName: PredefName, pDescript: PredefDescription }),
                    type: 'POST',
                    //dataType: "json",
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    //success: function (data) {
                    //    alert(data);
                    //}
                    //error: function (response) {
                    //    alert(response.responseText);
                    //},
                });
            });
```

I even tried putting ajaxError instead of ajaxComplete but it still doesnt work, any new suggestions? Also I realised that I should also include httpGet requests in this eqatuation.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle each ajax response and check it for 401 code which means - Not Authorized. Then reset your timer.

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, request, settings) {
   if(request.status === 401) {
       // reset timer
   }
});
```

You may try to handle another AJAX events:

[Global ajax event handlers in JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/)

Example from my project:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).ajaxError(function (event, jqxhr, settings, exception) {
        if (jqxhr.status == 401) {

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: could you write that out for me please? so I can test it.

Comment: @Vrankela look at my answer, I have modified it

Comment: I see it, I'm trying to test it now, but I think I ran into another situation that doesn't cover httpPost or ajax complete, I think it's an httpGet how do I cover that as well in the whole equation?

Comment: I can't make it to trigger

Comment: @Vrankela I think you even do not need JS timer on your page. Just handle 403 and do redirect. There are other global ajax events in JQuery. Read here http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/

Comment: I dont get it, none of the global ajax handlers are triggered, and I tried browser debug and see the status 200, allthough when I know the session expired and that it redirects me to the login as soon as I refresh like it should

Comment: @Vrankela Do you register your handler in `$(document).ready()`function? Look at my answer, I gave example from my project. And use code 401. 403 is forbidden

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67204/discussion-between-vrankela-and-jessejames).

Answer (score 0):

You are able to handle each ajax response and check it for 403 code That  is - Not Authorized. 
if not Authorized then you have to reset your time

Comment: could you write that out for me please? so I can test it.